# 20% off a product with a voucher

Tags: magento-1.8, promotions

I am sure its possible but can't see how its done.

I would like to set up a promotion where a customer gets 20% off a sku if they enter in a promotion code.

I presume I need to use "Percentage of a price discount" and set the shopping cart rule to be 20% and but it seems to be taking 20% off every product and not just the 1 SKU I want it to take off

Comment: Did you add the SKU as a condition to the coupon code? Please see this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5338305/how-to-create-a-coupon-on-specific-product-in-magento

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to add it under Actions where you set the discount see image below that should help[image: See image]